# Is bike fit really needed?

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, health, bike-setup

I'm having neck pains and muscle cramps when I go for long rides (> 90kms) . I don't know if the reason is due to big kms or is it the fit of the bike.
I live in India where a bike fit costs 12000 INR($195).
Do you suggest me to get a bike fit compulsorily ??

Thanks.

Comment: Well, a bike should fit you properly. The fact that you are having neck pains suggests that yours isn't fitting you very well. One way to get a fitting is to pay a professional to do it for you. But if you don't want to spend the cash on a fitting, there are a bunch of books that go into this. I'm bound to say, though, that if you're getting neck pains the odds are that you're going to have to spend some money in order to correct the existing problem.

Comment: 90 km is also a lot - are you sure you're ready for that much riding?

Comment: @Batman : hmm yes it is possible. Every weekend I ride for about 90- 120kms .. And weekdays about 40kms/day. :)

Comment: @thepeleton I do not regret a single penny spend on bike fitting. It is well worth the money, although $195 seems a bit much. I have to sayI live in Holland, where these thing are probably more common.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having pain and riding a lot of volume, it makes sense to get a fitting. Your other options are to

1. continue to experience the pain, possibly doing long term damage to your health.
2. reduce your volume of riding
3. get a different style bicycle with a more relaxed and upright geometry. Your fitter may recommend this anyways.

Comment: 4. Research bike fit yourself and adjust your bike accordingly. It won't be as good as a pro fitting, but it's definitely better than nothing.

Comment: I had this issue too: ITBS and long rides. Lots of rest and physical therapy didn't help. I was convinced to have the proper setting. I got fitted and the pain disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to get a professional bike fit to fix the problem, and the problem may not be fixed by a correct bike fit. If you do not know what the fitter is doing, be prepared to spend $200 for not much improvement.

The comment by @Neil "Research bike fit yourself and adjust your bike accordingly. It won't be as good as a pro fitting, but it's definitely better than nothing."  Has to be the best advise given to this question.

Even if you get a less than ideal bike fit doing it yourself, making even small changes can result in significant improvement. By understanding even a little of the dynamics, you should be able to get a fit that is comfortable, even if not 100% efficient - you may even get it spot on.

One advantage of reading up on bike fits is should you end up going to a professional fitter, he will be working with someone who at least has a basic understanding of the problems and compromises, and you will be able to ask intelligent questions and give more accurate feedback. You will be able to more accurately explain the compromises you want (e.g. Setting up for a time trial is not the same as a touring would be, road is somewhere in the middle).

For this reason alone, I do not recommend going to a fitter without having a basic understanding of what he will do and a clear understanding of what is important to you.

Comment: @thepeleton This is the second question you've asked on this topic. I thought you got good advice in the previous answers - did you follow them? Meanwhile, reduce the distances you are riding until you solve the problem, so that you don't cause an injury.

Comment: Wouldn't a bike fit be more useful at the point of purchasing a bike?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a bike fit is a must. 
While a bike fit may definitely help, I would experiment with the fit myself before resorting to pros. There is a great amount of things you can try yourself (e.g., move the seat, change the handlebar stem, move handlebar spacers, change the crank arms for different length, etc.).